# Prevent YouTube from using mobile data at all on Android 7 Nougat

Tags: 7.0-nougat, mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-s7

I would like to prevent YouTube from accessing mobile data at all. However, I cannot see how this is done in Android 7 Nougat on my Samsung Galaxy S7.

Has this feature been removed and replaced by the option to turn it off for background usage?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a firewall app and restrict YouTube to WiFi only.

For example, with [Onavo Protect, from Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.spaceship), it will establish a VPN connection that works like the firewall on non-rooted Android devices. You can restrict any app from using mobile data.

Comment: True. Can you suggest a particular one and provide its relevant use case?

Comment: Protect.https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.spaceship&hl=en
Protect Free VPN+Data Manager - Android Apps on Google Play
   . You it establish a vpn connection that works like firewall on non rooted Android devices. It's worth trying.you can restrict any app from using mobile data